# Testing if user is not login, redirect to login page

Tags: django, testing

Just testing if my application will redirect to the login page if the user is not logged in. The url `/confirmation/TEST01` where `TEST01` is a reverse url. It should redirect to `/accounts/login/?next=/confirmation/TEST01`

But I am getting an error:

`AssertionError: 404 != 302 : Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 404 (expected 302)`

Test.py

```
def test_redirect_to_login(self):
    response = self.client.get('/confirmation/TEST01/')
    self.assertRedirects(response, '/accounts/login/?next=/confirmation/TEST01', status_code=302, target_status_code=404, fetch_redirect_response=True)
```

Terminal

```
[30/Apr/2019 08:45:01] "GET /confirmation/XZC456 HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Not Found: /accounts/login/
[30/Apr/2019 08:45:01] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/confirmation/XZC456 HTTP/1.1" 404 2386
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the login_redirect decorator.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_redirect

@login_redirect
def my_view(request):
```